# How to select with conditions in relation in TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I want to find row in Friendship, where friendship.friends have users with ids equals to given. How can i do it via Repository and QueryBuilder?

Entities:

```
import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { UserToFriendship } from "./userToFriendship.entity";

@Entity()
export class Friendship {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @OneToMany(() => UserToFriendship, u => u.friendship, {
        eager: true
    })
    friends: UserToFriendship[]

    @Column({ default: false })
    accepted: boolean

}



import { User } from "src/users/entities/user.entity";
import { Entity, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Friendship } from "./friendship.entity";

@Entity()
export class UserToFriendship {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.friendships)
    user: User;

    @ManyToOne(() => Friendship, friendship => friendship.friends)
    friendship: Friendship;

}
```